# Why does resharper refactor(move) feature not update references - can I enable this?

Tags: refactoring, resharper

New to .net and loving resharper's refactor capability after many years of being spoilt by Eclipse.  When I move types however it doesn't seem to want to adjust references of the project to suit?? Is there some way to enable it? Surely if it can suggest the problem it can fix it!?

Comment: How do you you move your classes exactly? Are you using ReSharper's move commands?

Comment: Yes I use the move command. I should add here that I'm moving *between projects*. In eclipse this is no problem. References are added to projects as needed (can't remember if superfluous ones are removed automatically...). In Resharper land after a move between projects I have to go into the individual csproj files and add 10 or 15 references manually (or else do it painstakingly from the GUI). --Hope that makes more sense!

Comment: Are you talking about projects in the same solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. By default Resharper refactor (move) doesn't update the namespace of the class you are moving.  That means that regardless of where you put it, it will exist in the old namespace.

However, you can place your cursor over the namespace, and Alt-ENTER it to update to the proper namespace given the folder structure, or specify your own, and at that point it *will* update all the references to the class

Comment: Hi Nik. Please see comment to Ufuk

Answer (score 0):

You should use "Move to Folder" when you are moving classes between projects but it will only fix namespaces. ReSharper will not import references to projects for moved classes. Best thing to do would be to import references by hand before moving classes, then ReSharper should add using statements to class files.

Comment: Thanks Ufuk. Still leaves me with manual copying of references but in future I'll do that as the first step of a refactor of a type to another project